# IBAN number of PayPal Account

Tags: paypal

I travelled from a country (Where Paypal is not working) to a Country (where Paypal is working). I created my Paypal account here. I was supposed to get the amount for some fellowship but I didn't get my payment yet. I want to do some online purchases and I have some amount in my older bank account from my parent country. I want to transfer the amount to Paypal account. Is it possible? or How can I get my Paypal IBAN number from the Paypal mobile app? Please guide me. Many Thanks

Comment: PayPal accounts aren't bank accounts so they *don't have* IBAN numbers...?

Comment: PayPal accounts *may* have IBAN numbers, @user253751. I can transfer money from my bank account to my PayPal account by using an IBAN which PayPal provides (and that IBAN is specific to my PayPal account: I don't need to do anything extra to get the funds into my account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a bank account **in** the country where you created your PayPal account? And is this bank account linked to your PayPal account? If the fellowship funds that you are supposed to be receiving are to be sent *from* the country where Paypal does not provide services, they can be transferred via normal banking channels to your bank account, and you can use the money to make payments for purchases (including online purchases) via PayPal (at least for those online sites that offer PayPal as an alternative to the usual credit card payments). If someone (usually a person) is sending you money through PayPal, you get notification that someone has sent money, and you log in to your PayPal account (*please* don't click on the link in the e-mail or text message; log in directly to PayPal from a web browser or the app on your phone/tablet) and you have the option to put the money in the associated bank account, or forward parts of the payment to various online sites etc.